# Visual studio 2017 change background color of dark theme

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition with the dark theme.

I want to keep everything the same but just change the editor background color from RGB(30, 30, 30) to RGB(38, 41, 44) which is the Sublime Text background and is much easier on my eyes.

I want this to change for all languages. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Here is the UserVoice to vote for this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31062022-dark-theme-for-vsts-and-tfs-web-portal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following steps:

- Click on `Tools` menu
- Click on `Options`
- Click on `Fonts and Colors` (in `Environment`)
- `Show settings for:` should be set to `Text Editor`
- `Plain Text` should be selected in the `Display items:` list
- Click on the `Custom` button next to `Item background`
- Enter the RGB values you want in the bottom right of that dialog

Does that do what you were looking for?

Comment: what sdhould I have in the "Show settings for:" at the top ?

Comment: It should be `Text Editor`.

Answer (score 6):

From VS2017 menu, go to Tools --> Options 
On the left, under Environment, select General
On the right, first option is Color Theme, choose according to your taste.